# tpl.php files in subfolders

Tags: 6, theming

I am creating a big Drupal theme with lots of node types and lots of custom templates. Each having a very diffent look and feel. This is something I can not get round because the design was signed off before Drupal was decided as a platform. I wish to organise my files into folders.

```
templates/content_type/node-content_type.tpl.php
```

So for example

```
templates/page/node-page.tpl.php
templates/blog/node-blog.tpl.php
templates/node.tpl.php
```

The problem is drupal only scans for the templates files in the same folder as node.tpl.php.

Is it possible to get Drupal to scan into subfolders? Even if I need to hardcode where to look I don't mind.

Views does something which means it can look in subfolders but I don't know if that is because it defines its own type rather then a core type (node/page).

Comment: The Views module is not using a content type to show its results.

Comment: Sorry I meant that views can define tempalte files in subfolder locations and they are picked up and used.

Answer (score 3):

In D6, any custom templates (from core, such as node or page) must be in the same folder as the base tpl file in order to use the auto-recognition of theme files.

You may be able to specify additional template files (in D7 they're called theme hook suggestions) in a preprocess function in your theme's template.php. See the first code example at http://drupal.org/node/249726 to get you started.